# Linq inner join для списка в списке

Tags: c#, linq, join

У меня есть такие классы модели:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Есть хранилище этих объектов. Еще у меня есть ViewModels:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }       
    public CategoryViewModel Category { get; set; }
    public List<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }        
}
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
public class TagViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь мне нужно с помощью linq сделать `List<TransactionViewModel>` из `List<Transaction>`. Как сделал я:

```
Categories = ModelRepository.Categories.Select(p => new CategoryViewModel(p)));
Tags = ModelRepository.Tags.Select(p => new TagViewModel(p)));

var trans = from t in ModelRepository.Transactions
            join c in Categories on t.CategoryID equals c.ID
            select new TransactionViewModel()
            {
              ...,
              Category = c
            };

Transactions = trans.ToList();
```

Теперь при изменении любого `CategoryViewModel` в `Categories`, я сразу получу изменения для всех `TransactionViewModel.Category`.
Вопрос - как мне заполнить `TransactionViewModel.Tags`? Желательно с помощью LINQ. И обязательно чтобы при изменении любого `TagViewModel` в `Tags`, я сразу получал изменения во всех `TransactionViewModel.Tags`.

Comment: Не понятно, почему возникла необходимость создавать VM идентичную M, сразу M использовать нельзя?

Comment: Это упрощенный пример. На самом деле VM не идентична V

Answer (score 2):

Проблема с дизайном на лицо. Лучше еще раз его продумать, но в том, что я вижу сейчас, должно сработать такое:

```
var trans = from t in ModelRepository.Transactions
            join c in Categories on t.CategoryID equals c.ID
            select new TransactionViewModel
            {
                ...,
                Category = c,
                Tags = t.Tags.Select(guid => Tags.First(tag => tag.ID == guid)).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Я тоже так хотел, но, интересно, как тут будет с производительностью? А как улучшить дизайн? Я с тэгами никогда не работал, возможно есть проще решение